# Is there any sphinxsearch web frontend for searching?

Tags: python, sphinx

I am implementing full-text search for a large collection of databases Using Sphinxsearch. My final goal is to enable simultaneous search on all these databases through the web, with a google-like interface.

Before I roll up my sleeves to start from scratch I would like to know if is there any such project available as Open-Source. If it is implemented in Python, all the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try any of the plugins? at (does not work http://sphinxsearch.com/community/plugins/)
http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=third_party

Answer (score 0):

I made a self contained example front end 
http://nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example5-withcomments.phps

alas its PHP, but it might have some useful pointers.